# Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment 1st Edition

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, kernel

I am taking an [undergraduate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undergraduate#Adjective) operating systems class next semester and this is a recommended book. Would you still recommend *[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment)* (APUE) 1st Edition as opposed to the second edition?

I know you cannot recommend a book for a class you have not taken (not what I am asking for), but am wondering if anyone has read/owns both versions and whether or not they feel the 1st edition is still relevant or due to its age (written in 1992) I would be better off investing in the 2nd edition.  I don't know a ton about Unix and after taking a look at the 1st edition it seems like its a wealth of information. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good book, and the first edition is not very out of date. Much of the point of Unix is to limit how much the features and interfaces change over time. The older version of the book is still very valid, and the fact that there are only two editions in nineteen years speaks to the stability of the Unix libraries and utilities. Of course, your professor should be able to explain and differences you might encounter.

Answer (score 5):

From [the book's web site](http://www.apuebook.com/):

> The second edition of Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment has been updated to reflect contemporary operating systems and recent changes in standards. In addition, the example chapters were overhauled. The four platforms used to test the examples in the book include FreeBSD 5.2.1, Linux 2.4.22, Mac OS X 10.3, and Solaris 9. These platforms are a moving target, and most likely there are newer versions available now, so your mileage may vary.
>
> Major changes include the addition of a chapter on sockets, two chapters on threads, and the removal of the chapter discussing modem communication, although this lost chapter is available here. Additionally, the printer communication chapter was rewritten to account for today's network-based printers.

To my mind, the most valuable of these changes is the testing with modern platforms. APUE 1st edition barely mentioned Linux and of course didn't cover OS X at all since it hadn't been created yet. The 2nd edition fixes this.

That's not to say that APUE 1st edition is useless for Linux and OS X systems programming. I used it successfully with Linux for many years. I can't think of any time a topic it covered didn't implicitly cover at least one way to do it on Linux. The main difficulty is that where there is more than one way to do something, APUE usually gives them all, but with the 1st edition you had to just try them all to find out which one Linux supported. It's a worse problem with OS X, because its kernel is less [ecumenical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ecumenical#Adjective) than Linux's.

I don't miss the chapters on threads and sockets in my 1st edition copy, because I have other books for that. As a new systems programmer, you will find them valuable until you find a reason to get something more comprehensive in those areas. They're both topics worthy of full books. (Full shelves, really.)

Anyway, the bottom line is I still have my 1st edition copy despite buying the 2nd edition for work. The 1st edition copy just went home is all. It's still useful.